# timepicker is not loading properly

Tags: jquery, css, timepicker

I have the following code

HEAD

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/jquery.timepicker.css'></link>
<script src='https://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/jquery.timepicker.js'></script>
```

BODY

```
<td class='int_label'>Start Time: </td>
<script>$('.timepicker').each(function(){ 
$(this).timepicker();});
</script><td >
<input type='text'  name='start_time_0' id='timepicker' class='timepicker'  /></td>
```

It is executing, I can see that it populates something , however the result is too dirty:

- just one of the inputs receives code
- I can see a lot of parts of the "time" spread among the screen, and eventually no dropdown is shown

What is being my mistake?
Does it matter that I am loading several libraries:

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js'></script><script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js'></script><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css'></link><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href=''>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><link href="../library/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="simple.css" /><script>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] because when I try to reproduce the issue it works absolutely fine with multiple timepickers.

Comment: Are you calling jquery.min.js somewhere other than in the head, like the answer below suggests? Like Jamiec, I can get the code you have to work but not in the order you've presented it here. As for the style issue, you need to include enough of the CSS here for us to see the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As I tested your code and I found that you missed calling your  jquery.min.js file in your code head.

```js
<script>$('.timepicker').each(function(){ $(this).timepicker();});</script>
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/jquery.timepicker.css'></link>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/jquery.timepicker.js'></script>


<td class='int_label'>Start Time: </td>
 
<td><input type='time'  name='start_time_0' id='timepicker' class='timepicker'  /></td>
```

```html
OR you can check with this 
https://www.jonthornton.com/jquery-timepicker/
```